# Does the name Alex in German has its dimunitive variant?

Tags: person-names, diminutive

It's a pretty common name but I don't think it fits with -chen or -lein

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Alex* is the short form of *Alexander* (for male persons) and of *Alexandra* (for female persons). And of both names there are diminutive forms:

- Alexanderchen (m)
- Alexandrachen (f)

All names are stressed on the 3rd syllable ("xan"): Ale**xan**der, Ale**xan**dra, Ale**xan**derchen, Ale**xan**drachen

The "ch" in the diminutive syllable is always pronounced as [ç] (it's the "ich-CH", not the "ach-CH" which has the pronunciation symbol [x]). If you do it wrong (wrong syllable stressed and wrong sound for "ch", then the female diminutive form would sound like Alexan-Drachen (German "Drachen" = English "dragon"). Because it's easy to make this mistake, most girls named Alexandra don't like this diminutive form.

I know only one Alexandra, and she hates "Alexandrachen". She prefers to be called "Alex" which, as a short form of a name, already is kind of a diminutive form.

But it's also possible to have a diminutive form of "Alex": Just add an "i" to the end. This is a very common German diminutive suffix for names. (Only for names!) It works best for names that have only one syllable and end in a consonant. "Alex" ends in a consonant, but it has two syllables, so it's not the perfect candidate for this suffix, but maybe some people think it's okay.

- Franz -> Franzi
- Klaus -> Klausi
- Fritz -> Fritzi
- Tim -> Timmi
- Bernd -> Berndi
- **Alex -> Alexi**

btw: Short female first names seem always to end in an vowel, that's why I didn't find female examples for the i-suffix. (Except "Franzi" which can also be the short form of "Franziska")

Comment: You can also use Alexilein.

Comment: I suppose "Alexel" is theoretically possible, but I wasn't able to find any examples. A diminutive doesn't necessarily have to start with the start of the full name. So in English there are "Alex", "Lex", and "Xander". I don't know if that ever happens in German though.

Comment: In eastern Germany you might be fine with using the Russian diminutive _Sascha_.

Comment: "Franzi", "Klausi", etc. are *affectionate* forms (like, i.e. "Bärbel" or "Uschi"), but i doubt they are technaically diminutives. i.e. the diminutive of "Franz" would be "Fränzchen", not "Franzi".

Comment: @JonathanScholbach Do you know any examples where this is used? I grew up in East-Berlin and the first time I encountered the Alex -> Sascha connection was when reading Tolstoi. I haven't ever seen it used for a German and Alex/ Alexander is a pretty common name.

Comment: "Sascha" _is_ common in Germany, but as a name of itself, and most Germans would not associate it with "Alexander" at all. "Lex" / "Lexa" are probably more widely understood, and "Lexi" definitely works as a diminuitive.

Comment: "Alexandrachen" is formally correct, but I wouldn't use it because it ends with "drachen".

Comment: There is also the possibility of "Lexi"

Comment: Ad _Sascha_: the Austrian president, Alexander van der Bellen, is known to be called like that by friends. But he has ancestors from Estonia and the Russian empire. Otherwise, I concur that the knowledge that _Sascha_ is related to _Alexander_ cannot be generally assumed.

Answer (score 0):

A common diminutive is Xandi or Xandl, using the stressed syllable of Alexander to build it. This is also used for the female form Alexandra.

examples:

- https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Huber_(Volleyballspieler),
- https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Schl%C3%A4ffer,
- https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_Sea,
- https://gourmeetme.com/about.html,
- http://www.xandis-galerie.de/

Comment: This is the first time, as a German, that I come across that form, and 4 of the 5 examples are Austrian, 1 is from Rosenheim in Bavaria, so "nearly Austria".